# How to delete a file/directory with '$' in the name using powershell or cmd

Tags: windows, git, special-characters

I accidentally created a directory (programmatically) whose name starts with `$`. All efforts to delete it have failed, via powershell, cmd, explorer. It doesn't want to recognize the `$` as part of the name, and probably isn't interpreting it as it either. I've seen some info on removing files/dirs with leading/trailing dots or whitespace, but that doesn't seem to work in this case. Has anyone else seen this? I doubt i can delete the repo i'm working in because of this. Thanks.

Comment: `$` is a normal allowed character for files and directories. You should be able to rename it just fine using the Windows Explorer. If that doesn’t work, then something else is going on. What exactly is the error?

Comment: If you still have problems, try escaping it in your delete commands with `\$`

Comment: @CJxD That's horrible advice for Powershell/cmd users. `\ ` is not a metacharacter, and couldn't be, as it's already so extremely widely used as a path component separator.

Comment: @hvd You're right. Using `\ ` as an escape is application-specific in Windows. Instead `^` should be tried although quotes are the main method of escaping.

Comment: @CJxD To be honest, I'd be surprised if this was a quoting problem, especially considering it failed for the OP from the GUI as well, but if a quoting problem it is, then indeed, `^` and double quotes are the things to try, at least in cmd. It's a pity the OP now found something that worked, but is unable to tell what it was. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `rm '$name' -recurse -force` in powershell, and `rd /q /s $name` in cmd, and `rm -rf '$name'` in bash.

Comment: One of those ended up working. It didn't seem to at first, but the dir disappeared eventually. Strange problem; hopefully it won't come back. Thanks everyone.